# Intellij IDEA Java no web page found for the following web address: http://localhost:8090

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

When I changed project directory in my Java project on Intellij IDEA and when I started the project I got error what "no web page found for the following web address: http://localhost:8090". My Tomcat settings is below. I fixed all settings for new directory but I can't start the project. How can I fix it ?

[Tomcat settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5P1r.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `WAR` file, which should be deployed in part `"Deployment"`. And you need to set the application context e.g. to `/my_web_war`